# Android custom view (very basic)

Tags: android, view

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to implement a custom view to act as a "custom menu button" for my app.

I followed the instructions at http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html but by the end of the implementation I get a message saying "Unfortunately customviews1 has stopped" and the app just shut's down.

My approach is very simple and I cannot find any reference about solving this basic problem. Here's what I'm doing:

1. create a new Android project in Eclipse named "customviews1"
2. I run the project and it shows a "Hello World" TextView on the "activity_main.xml" layout file
3. I add a new class named MyCustomView that extends "View" to the "src" folder of the project

   ```
   public class MyCustomView extends View {
       public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }
   }
   ```
4. I remove the "TextView" tag from activity_main.xml and add a "customview1" to it:

   ```
   <com.example.customviews1.MyCustomView android:id="@+id/myCustomView1" />
   ```
5. I run the app again and I got the message saying "Unfortunately customviews1 has stopped" and the app shuts down.

Is there any code I'm missing here?

Thanks for any clue,
Regards,
Victor Reboucas

Comment: did you try to add your custom view programmatically? Please could you add the whole main.xml, maybe it will be easier to investigate your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you check your LogCat output you will find that an error saying that you have to specify layout_width and layout_height in your layout.

so write:

```
<com.example.customviews1.MyCustomView android:id="@+id/myCustomView1" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot... that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cant do that on that way , you must overide all methods from view class like `onDraw()` and other , read more about it

Answer (score 0):

Please try as following.I tried this one and success.
first you have to override all three super class constructor.

To show some thing in view you have to override `onDraw()` method.

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {
    //variables and objects
    Paint p;

    //override all three constructor
    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    //do what you want in this method
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText("This is custom view this can be added in xml", 10, 100, p);
        canvas.drawRect(20, 200, 400, 400, p);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
    //all the initialization goes here
    private void init() {
        p =new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

In `xml` file include it as following example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.sanath.customview.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/myCustomView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you